# WebRTC - one way broadcasting

Tags: webrtc, openwebrtc

If a user opens a webcam broadcast , how many viewers can join and watch ? Does WebRTC has limits for it ?

Comment: WebRTC is not about bradcasting, but maybe this opensource project can help you: https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/broadcast/

Comment: i did some digging about webrtc and im just new to this but what do you have any suggestions for implementing one-way broadcasting ?thanks by the way

Comment: You can set WebRTC connection to a broadcasting server; I am not sure if such setup can be hosted by a browser